# What's a modern toolset for PHP/JavaScript-development?

Tags: php

I'm a single developer with half a dozen reasonably popular projects - most of them WordPress plugins.

All my web development is *still* done in Notepad++, *constantly* using google to read source code and documentation (jquery, PHP and WordPress). I *do* use SVN but sometimes can not control the server side (eg. WordPress plugin repos)

Right now I'm spending too much time doing very, very stupid things. Almost all of which would be non-issues if the right tools were involved.

So I ask you; **what is a modern toolset for doing PHP, HTML, JavaScript and CSS?**

- I'm looking for auto-completion and code hinting, not only for my own code but also for jQuery, WordPress and PHP-natives
- Is proper PHP debugging possible? (break points, a console - I'll take anything!)
- I would love auto-minifying of scripts and stylesheets (without creating a hassle with manually changing file paths in the source etc).
- Can I please also have offline documentation available within my editor? (though code hinting would alleviate most of the problem)
- An explorer pane for easy access to files in my project, global search (& replace), etc. etc.

And I'd vastly prefer something that is portable. I tend to run all tools from my DropBox - keeping everything available at all machines. FlashDevelop, Notepad++, puTTY, FileZilla and XAMPP works really well in that respect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quite like [Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/products/studio3) when using HTML/JS/CSS. I haven't tried it with PHP, but it seems to support that as well. It's also extendable, so if there's something that you need, you can use the scripts and commands available to customize it.

Answer (score 1):

I would defintely recommend either Aptana Studio or ZendStudio. They both seem to have everything that you're looking for. You can also create custom code snippets in Aptana(not sure about ZendStudio) for your jquery code.